Bound for solution heat equation with Neumann condition
Assume that $H$ solves
$$
H_t = aH_{xx},\\
H(0,x) = 0,\\
H_x(t,0) = h(t).
$$
A solution of this equation can be given in integral form as
$$
H(t, x)=-\int_0^t h(s) \bar{K}(t-s, z,x) d s,
$$
where $\bar{K}(t, z, x)=K(t, z-x)+K(t,-z-x)$ with $K$ the heat kernel. Seems like you can get the following estimate for $H$ for a finite time $t_0$
$$
\|H\|_{C\left(\left[0, t_0\right]; C_0\right)} \leqslant \frac{\|h\|_{\infty}}{2 (a \pi)^{1 / 2}}.
$$
The question is, that I am not able to get this estimate, I was thinking that It should be using the integral form of the solution, but still I am not able to do it. So, any help would be useful.
Thank you in advance.

Sorry if this is a easy question, but I am a bit unfamiliar with the notation. Here what is the norm on $H$, is it just the supremum norm on $[0,t_0]$?

@person it is the supremum as you said

Is your norm just $\sup_{x>0,0\le t\le t_0}|H(x,t)|$?

@Andrew ya it is just that

One cannot get an estimate better that values at the side boundary:
$$
H(t, 0)=-\int_0^t h(s) \bar{K}(t-s, 0,0) d s=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a \pi}}\int_0^t
\frac{h(s)}{\sqrt{t-s}}\,ds
$$
and from the maximum principle (for the given bounded solution)
$$
|H(t, x)|\le \sup_{0\le s \le t}|H(s, 0)|\le \frac{|h|_{\infty}}{\sqrt{a\pi}}\int_0^t\frac{ds}{\sqrt{t-s}}=
\frac{2\sqrt{t}\,|h|_{\infty}}{\sqrt{a\pi}}.
$$
From the other hand putting $h(t)\equiv1$ we get equality:
$$
|H(t, 0)|=\frac{2\sqrt{t}\,|h|_{\infty}}{\sqrt{a\pi}}.
$$
Therefore the desired uniform  estimate, not depending on $t$, doesn't hold.
In physical interpretation $h(t)\equiv1$ means a unit heat inflow through the boundary that leads to temperature growth on the boundary as $\sim\sqrt{t}$. In fact, temperature of every point $x>0$ tends to infinity as $t\to+\infty$.
